# Fixing the representative of a coset for a function.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am working on through a proof from lecture. Given that $K\leq H\leq G$, we are constructing a bijection $$f: G/H\times H/K\rightarrow G/K$$
Since $G/H$ is the set of cosets, we can fix the representative of the cosets in creating a well defined function. That is $$g_1H = g_2H$$
if and only if $g_1 = g_2$.

That last part about fixing the representatives of each coset leaves me uneasy. Since we know that multiple representatives prevents us from creating an operation on any set of cosets, I am not sure why we can fix our representatives.

If that is true then the rest of the proof follows.Why are we allowed fix representatives of the cosets for this function. Is it related to mapping cosets from one set to a different set?

Comment: If you pick a representative and use it to define a function, then you need to show that if you picked a different representative from the same class, then you would get the same output to your function. Is this your worry?

Comment: @James My professor said that we could fix our representatives for the cosets so that a set is only represented by one element and we would then not truly need to check if a coset was represented by a different element. Which I think is wrong, or at least is very dangerous and I do not know why we can use it in this case.

Comment: I imagine there was some kind of miscommunication. Presumably, your professor meant to say that even though we define the function in terms of a representative from the coset, it is actually defined on the whole coset because it didn't matter what we picked (this would need to be proved).

Comment: I don't think I agree with @James here. Choosing different representatives will give you a different bijection. But that's okay; you're only asked to find one bijection.

Comment: (I'm assuming that your function is something like $(gH, hK) \mapsto ghK$, even though you haven't specified it. This *definitely* depends on which representatives you pick. But we're not trying to show that there's only *one* such bijection, just that at least one exists!)

Comment: @Billy So is it still a bijection if different representatives give different answers? Shouldn't this create a well-defined issue?

Comment: @Billy So would we need to have a function defined for every possible representative combinations?

Comment: Yes. The point is that $f$ *depends on* those representatives. If $R$ and $R'$ are two sets of representatives for the cosets, then the functions $f_R$ and $f_{R'}$ you get out of them will usually be different. Both will be bijections, they just won't be the same. This would only be a well-definedness issue if we were trying to claim that $f_R = f_{R'}$.

Comment: @Billy To rubber ducky back my understanding, we fix the representatives to create some function $f_i$ which is well defined and we show is a bijection for the fixed representatives. Then for this function, how can we be certain that the function receives or identifies the correct representative?

Comment: It's not the job of the function to "identify" anything - it's our job to give the function an exhaustive and unambiguous list of rules. (For instance, "if you are given coset $C_i$, you should proceed using representative $x_i$".) Perhaps an example will make this clearer, so I'll post one in an answer.

Comment: @Billy I think you are likely correct! I haven't thought about the isomorphism theorems in a long time nor what map would be defined here. I was being lazy. Thanks for cleaning up after my mess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments above: $f$ will depend on the choice of the set of representatives.

I think the best way to see what's going on is with an example, so let

- $G = \{e, g, g^2, g^3, g^4, g^5\}$, a cyclic group of order 6,
- $H = \{e, g^3\}$, the unique subgroup of order 2,
- $K = \{e\}$.

$G/H$ is a cyclic group of order 3, and we could pick a bunch of different lists of our favourite representatives. Two possible choices are, for example,

- $R^{G/H}_1 = \{e, g, g^2\}$
- $R^{G/H}_2 = \{e, g, g^5\}$

-- that is, I've just swapped the $g^2$ for a $g^5$.

$H/K$ is a cyclic group of order 2, and only has one possible set of representatives: $\{e, g^3\}$. (This is because I've taken $K$ to be trivial, for the sake of simplicity, so that we can just ignore it in this example.) So we're forced to set both $R^{H/K}_1$ and $R^{H/K}_2$ -- our lists of our chosen representatives of $H/K$ -- equal to this set.

We can now define our functions

$$f_1, f_2: G/H \times H/K \to G/K$$

as follows: given some cosets $xH\in G/H$ and $yK\in H/K$, the function $f_1$ will look up our chosen representative for $xH$ in the list $R^{G/H}_1$, and our chosen representative for $yK$ in $R^{H/K}_1$; and $f_2$ will do the same, but using the lists $R^*_2$. Both functions then proceed to multiply these elements in order and stick a $K$ at the end and output the result.

So, for instance: consider the cosets $(eH, eK)$. $f_1$ will look up the representatives in lists $R^*_1$, and find that they're $e$ and $e$; $f_2$ will look up the representatives in $R^*_2$ and get the same answers. The result will be $f_1(eH, eK) = f_2(eH, eK) = e\cdot e\cdot K = eK$.

But consider the cosets $(g^2H, eK)$. When $f_1$ looks up the representatives, it finds $g^2$ and $e$; but when $f_2$ looks them up, it finds $g^5$ and $e$. So $f_1(g^2H, eK) = g^2K$, but $f_2(g^2H, eK) = g^5K$. These aren't equal (as elements of $G/K$).

You can visualise the outputs of $f_1$ and $f_2$ by drawing a table for each: 3 rows (one for each coset of $G/H$), two columns (for cosets of $H/K$). You'll notice that, in both cases, all 6 outputs are distinct - in other words, both are injective.

Comment: So this creates many functions for the specific case that we are looking at and each one of these functions is a bijection. This is the part where I am getting confused, how does having bijections for every possible case show that we then have a bijection from $G/H\times H/K \rightarrow G/K$

Comment: I don't understand your question. $f_1$ is a bijection $G/H\times H/K\to G/K$. So is $f_2$. Any one of them will do.

Comment: I guess, why is ok that our function is dependent on the input for its definition. Why do we not need a function that works for every input.

Comment: Or would this bijection which I think we need be allowed to be a set of functions like a function with cases?

Comment: $f_1$ *is* a function that works for every input. We had to make some choices in order to define it, but once it's defined, you can check that it works. And no, you're not required to give a set of functions.

Comment: I think you're getting hung up on the meaning of the question. What would you do if I asked you to give me a bijection $\{0,1,2,3,4\} \to \{v,w,x,y,z\}$? Presumably you'd just write one down - e.g. $0\mapsto v, 1\mapsto w, \dots$. What if I then said "but your function depends on its definition, and I could have defined a different one, such as $0\mapsto z, 1\mapsto y, \dots$"? Hopefully you'd say "that's true, and your function is just as good as mine, but the fact that there are lots of possible answers doesn't mean that we need to do anything more than give one, like the question asks".

Comment: I think its starting to click, to give a different example. If we made a function  $g: \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ and defined $g(p/q) = p + q$, but we require that $p$ and $q$ are relatively prime.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the sort of thing that's going on.